onLogin no es una funcion
que tal soy un estudiante del tercer ciclo de la carrera de computación e informática ,estoy realizando un login que ya tengo registrado en mi base de datos , lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer el inicio de sesión me sale que mi función onLogin no es una función. estoy tratando de poder solucionarlo pero siempre me sale ese mismo error, necesito su ayuda ya que tengo que entregar este proyecto en 1 semana y me siento frustrado. Dejo evidencias de mi código que estoy usando React y Node para el backend .
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

const Login = ({ onLogin }) => { // Cambiado para recibir `onLogin` desde `props`
    const [correo, setCorreo] = useState('');
    const [contraseña, setContraseña] = useState('');
    
    const handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", { correo, contraseña })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    if (typeof onLogin === 'function') {
                        onLogin(true); // Llama a la función onLogin con true como argumento
                    } else {
                        console.error('onLogin no es una función');
                    }
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'Credenciales incorrectas',
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error al hacer login:', error);
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'No se pudo conectar al servidor. Intente más tarde.',
                });
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="login-container">
            <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="correo">Correo:</label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        id="correo"
                        name="correo"
                        value={correo}
                        onChange={(e) => setCorreo(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="contraseña">Contraseña:</label>
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        id="contraseña"
                        name="contraseña"
                        value={contraseña}
                        onChange={(e) => setContraseña(e.target.value)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

si necesitan saber mas del codigo y la estructura me lo hacen saber muchas gracias .

Sugiero que edites la pregunta, agrega el componente que pasa la prop onLogin' parece que se esta enviando otro tipo y no una función
